# Cannot cast from source type to destination type (Not Involving Components)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been modifying kengine's demo (Which the code is open source) and encountered a problem after I assembled the last scene or tried to select my character.

I've tried countless things such as reinputting the variable and trying to make the variable be declared before the word account is used. Generally my head is just hurting from figuring out another issue and I really want to resolve these issues today.
The Error I receive is: InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.

I was unable to find any that had a instance like mine where no component command's were being used near the line specified (its used in the script, but the line it specified isn't associated with it nor could I find any using KBEngine's API.

Cannot cast from source type to destination type Script.Start () at line 145

I have suspicions this involves output that the script isn't receiving

Whenever the script is used, the scene loads for a couple seconds before going back to the last scene. If you need to see all my

```
void Start () {
    Common.DEBUG_MSG("selavatar_ui::Start: " + started);

    if(started == false)
    {
        started = true;
        log_label.color = UnityEngine.Color.green;
        log_label.text = "Getting List of Roles...";

        Monitor.Enter(KBEngineApp.app.entities);
        Account account = (Account)KBEngineApp.app.player();
        Monitor.Enter(account.avatars);
        Dictionary<UInt64, Dictionary<string, object>> avatars = account.avatars;
        Monitor.Exit(account.avatars);
        Monitor.Exit(KBEngineApp.app.entities);

        onReqAvatarList(avatars);

        installEvents();
    } 

    windowsize = 30;
    //autoSetPosition();
}
```

If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: You haven't really included enough information to reproduce the problem. What project are you talking about? If it's open source, a link would be great. At best, it appears that whatever type is returned by `KBEngineApp.app.player()` can't be reliably converted to an `Account`. I don't know the relationship between those types, so it's hard to comment more specifically than that.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/p4ABbZaW and https://github.com/kbengine/kbengine_unity3d_warring/tree/master/Assets       It uses chinese so you might need google translate or something for certain commented lines. I mainly touched other scripts except for translating some labels.